# javascript custom file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a html5 template. I have some plugin. so I created a different javascipt file to call them(just for organize the things in better way). I'm not a javascript pro, so I think I might have some problem in that js file, because some plugins are not working when it is active(like Megafolio grid plugin, GoUp plugin). so if anyone tell me if I have any bugs in my js file, that would be great. here it is:

```
 <!--Image Grid-->

    $(function() {

        $( '#ri-grid' ).gridrotator( {
            slideshow : false,
            onhover : true,
            rows : 3,
            columns : 8,
            maxStep : 2,
            interval : 2000,
            w1024 : {
                rows : 3,
                columns : 6
            },
            w768 : {
                rows : 3,
                columns : 5
            },
            w480 : {
                rows : 3,
                columns : 4
            },
            w320 : {
                rows : 3,
                columns : 4
            },
            w240 : {
                rows : 3,
                columns : 3
            },
        } );

    });




<!--Owl Carouosel-->
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".custom1").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 4000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:4,
            nav:true           
        }
    }
});
});

<!--Owl Carouosel 2-->
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".custom2").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: false,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    loop:true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    /*animateOut: 'slideOutDown',*/
    animateOut: 'fadeOutDown',
    animateIn: 'fadeInUp',
    items: 1,
    margin: 30,
    stagePadding: 30,
    smartSpeed: 450
});
});




<!--Skill Barl-->
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
            width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
        },6000);
    });
});




<!--Form Validation-->
$(function()
{
    // Validation
    $("#sky-form").validate(
    {                   
        // Rules for form validation
        rules:
        {
            name:
            {
                required: true
            },
            email:
            {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message:
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            }
        },

        // Messages for form validation
        messages:
        {
            name:
            {
                required: 'Please enter your name',
            },
            email:
            {
                required: 'Please enter your email address',
                email: 'Please enter a VALID email address'
            },
            message:
            {
                required: 'Please enter your message'
            }
        },

        // Ajax form submition                  
        submitHandler: function(form)
        {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit(
            {
                success: function()
                {
                    $("#sky-form").addClass('submited');
                }
            });
        },

        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement: function(error, element)
        {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: my bet is you included jQuery library in page more than once

Comment: no. I just include it once.

Comment: no one is helping, but giving me negative ratings. did I made any mistake?

Comment: so what errors are thrown in browser console then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you have the proper import order :

```
 <script src="YOUR_JQUERY_VERSION_.js"></script>
 <script src="JQUERY_UI_VERSION.js"></script> // OPTIONAL
 <script src="OTHER_JQUERY_LIBRARIES.js"></script> //OPTIONAL
 <script src="YOUR_OWN_LIBRARY.js"></script>
```